# Docker: Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ (Path here) /merged : too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: docker, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to run minikube with the following command:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

but it keeps giving me this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to 
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a0d24fcc3839411f64db067596135b1402fc1f98252ce3a09cb79b0ff2cabe41- 
init/merged: too many levels of symbolic links.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

- I have tried reinstalling the minikube both using chocolatey and .exe file.
- Tried stopping and deleting minikube cluster from docker.
- Tried reinstalling docker and all of it's services are running properly.
- Environment variables have also been set properly for kubectl and minikube.

is there something I'm missing out on..?

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjzyR.png)

[here's the image displaying the running containers using the docker run command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peQzP.png)

Comment: This looks more like a Docker problem than a minikube problem. Are you able to successfully start containers using `docker run`?

Comment: @sanyma it looks like there is an issue with how you're specifying your attached volumes in your run command, but it is difficult to tell from the picture you posted.  Can you update your question to include your docker run command

Comment: @larsks Yes, I tried running Ubuntu and Nginx in a Docker container, and everything appears to be working as it should... I can also create docker files and images, as well as run commands like "docker commit." So perhaps docker appears to be working properly.btw I am also running low on my SSD space (only 4GB is left on my C drive)...does this have anything to do with the issue.?

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your time! I've updated my query with the "docker run command" image.